# Rails 5 - can I type an ActiveRecord code into console to examine the record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I seem to remember reading that one can use the ActiveRecord code (not sure what to call this) in the console to help in debugging. So if I see an ActiveRecord code in an error message or log file like this:

(I have a Vote model), then I believe I should be able to use this in the console as follows:

```
> v = #<Vote::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x000000120745d8>
```

and examine the record, eg:

```
> v.id
=> 228

> v.user.name
=> "Thomas"
```

I'm not able to get this to work and can't find any documentation on it so would be grateful for some guidance.

Comment: `ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation` is a collection of records, you cant call instance methods on collection.

Comment: Thanks. While it's not the main question, how do I extract the record from the collection when I know there is only one in it?

Comment: `vote = v.first`